# iOS: Using Instruments to detect nil value insertion into dictionary

Tags: ipad, nsdictionary, instruments, ios5.1

I am trying to use Instruments to detect following error. Could someone please tell me if it is possible to get the line that causes this exception using Instruments. Thanks.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: attempt to insert nil value (key: username)'
```